# Apache Alias forbidden access

Tags: apache, http-status-code-403, apache2.4, fedora-25

Apache Cannot serve Alias to folder outside DocumentRoot

```
Alias /hello /test

<Directory "/test">
  Options FollowSymLinks
  AllowOverride FileInfo
  Order Allow,Deny
  Allow from All
  Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 1):

Soruce: https://www.petefreitag.com/item/793.cfm

Just had to run:

chcon -R --reference=/var/www /test

Explanation:

**If Running Security Enhanced Linux (SELinux)**

Another possibility for this error is that you are running SELinux (Security Enhanced Linux), inwhich case you need to use chcon to apply the proper security context to the directory. One easy way to do this is to copy from a directory that does work for example /var/www/

Comment: Is https://www.petefreitag.com/item/793.cfm the source of your explanation?

Comment: I found it in a different blog, but seems that is the original soruce.